# https redirect only works sometimes

Tags: ssl, sitemap, http-status-code-301, google-search

There are two `domain` names:

1.one long (example: `MaryJaneFamily.com`)

2.one short (`MaryJane.com`).

The `301 redirect` works correctly from `EXISTING` links from various web sites (from when the site had `no ssl`).

The redirect domain name appears but gives a `"insecure  site"` warning and it appears as `https://MaryJane.com`.

The primary domain name does not show up in google listings at all.

I have validated the full domain name with google and provided a new `sitemap` to google.

The `sitemap` submission is not showing any errors. `DNS` for primary domain name shows it is fully propagated.

The link that appears in google is not the primary domain but the forwarded domain name with an `"s"` added to the http - selecting that link brings to you a  `"insecure site"` warning screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appear that your SSL certificat is maybe not valid or generated and auto-signed by your server. You have to use a SSL certificate certified by high autority trusted domain. A lot of hosting services can sell you a validated and trusted SSL certificate, or some companies like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) can give you for free (with some other protections and services like CDN, DDoS protect, firewall...etc).

If you want to do it yourself, you can use [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to make your own trusted certificate (remember that you will have to renew this all 3 months but you can easily automate it).

Well, you can read [this guide](https://serverguy.com/security/types-of-ssl-certificates/) to know more about SSL certificates and which you sould use.

I hope it will help.

Comment: The web site already has a valid quality SSL -- but somehow it appears that the 301 redirect is the issue since it appears as httpS://MaryJane.com (not http://MaryJane.com) - It is my understanding that domain names cannot have an SSL only  the website can. I "think" the issue is related to the problem that  redirect  appears online as "httpS://MaryJane.com" instead of "http://MaryJane.com. But I don't know how to change that. I will read the guide you provided links for to see if that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a "return 301" for forced SSL in your sites config? If you don't force SSL then you will receive both secure and insecure ports.